# Is an Agent just a nice way of wrapping global state?

Tags: akka, actor, agent

I've been learning akka in java and scala and have yet to fully see the proper use of Agents. I worry about using them because they contain state and it feels like they are just nice little wrappers of that evil thing programmers name global state. So I have some questions

1. Are Agents a wrapper for global state?
2. What is the difference between actors both having a reference to an Agent, as opposed to a Remote object (if we're talking distrubuted) with synchronized methods?
3. What advantages are there to using an Agent instead of an Actor which you would send a message to asking for the current value of one of its variables and it would send a message back informing the asker what the value is at the time it responds?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by Agent. Akka uses the actor model (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model) where the programming primitives are called actors. Could you please clarify what an agent in your case is?

Comment: @Philipp, if you haven't heard of a term on stackoverflow, such as 'Agent' you should maybe google it before commenting, otherwise you may appear silly. Agents are part of Akka, you go do some googling and then get back to me. Another suggestion is don't give people generic Wikipedia links, anyone who is capable of using stackoverflow probably has already exhausted Wikipedia.